# Make everything zeros in a numpy 2d-array outside of bounding box

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Say I have a numpy 2d-array like:

```
>>> ar
array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 3],
       [4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 2, 1],
       [5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4],
       [1, 5, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4],
       [7, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 5, 6, 7]])
```

I define a bounding box like follows, and I want that all the items in `ar` which are **not** in the bounding box all become zeros:

```py
>>> my_bbox = ((2, 7), (1, 3))

>>> make_zeros(ar, bounding_box)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Beyond the "obvious" (and also ugly and inefficient) looping methods, is there a slice/vector-type operation to achieve that? I believe that array masks might work, but not sure how specifically.

Comment: SImplest is to assign the sub-array to a larger `np.zeros` array.  Or construct a `mask` and multiply.

Comment: Is part of the issue that your index will have arbitrary dimension?

Comment: @hpaulj it can be seen from example that resulting array preserves dimensions

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, absolutely!

Comment: Would you be willing to swap the order of the tuples to correspond to the dimensions? Rows come first.

Answer (score 1):

You might like to create a copy of array and then write needed submatrix on top of it:

```
ar_zeroed = np.zeros(ar.shape).astype(int)
slice1, slice2 = slice(my_bbox[0][0], my_bbox[0][1]+1),
                 slice(my_bbox[1][0], my_bbox[1][1]+1)
ar_zeroed[slice2, slice1] = ar[slice2, slice1]
```

Note that dimensions are swapped in your bounding box

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 3],
                [4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 2, 1],
                [5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4],
                [1, 5, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4],
                [7, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 5, 6, 7]])

print(arr, end='\n\n')

first_idx = (1, 3)
second_idx = (2, 7)

first_slice = slice(first_idx[0], first_idx[1] + 1)
second_slice = slice(second_idx[0], second_idx[1] + 1)

res = np.zeros_like(arr)
res[first_slice, second_slice] = arr[first_slice, second_slice]

print(res)
```

Output:

```
[[1 2 3 1 2 3 1 7 2 3]
 [4 3 2 4 5 5 6 5 2 1]
 [5 4 2 4 6 2 4 2 1 4]
 [1 5 6 1 4 2 2 4 1 4]
 [7 4 5 6 2 5 3 5 6 7]]

[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 4 5 5 6 5 0 0]
 [0 0 2 4 6 2 4 2 0 0]
 [0 0 6 1 4 2 2 4 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

I'm almost certain it can still be improved, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do "something" to the slices `ar[1:3+1, 2:7+1]`. The expression in square brackets is turned into a tuple of `slice` objects by the interpreter. You can programatically create the same sequence of slices and pass them in as the index to an array. This can be used in a number of approaches.

The "simplest" is to create a new array of zeros and assign the required swath:

```
index = tuple(slice(start, stop + 1) for start, stop in bounding_box)
result = np.zeros_like(ar)
result[index] = ar[index]
```

Another would be to make a mask, invert it, and set the elements it corresponds to to zero:

```
mask = np.ones(ar.shape, dtype=np.bool)
mask[index] = zero
ar[mask] = 0
```

Finally, you could just set the appropriate swaths to zeros directly. This is probably less optimal than the other approaches, unless you code it very carefully to not have overlaps in the corners:

```
index = [slice(None) for _ in range(ar.ndim)]
for dim, (start, stop) in enumerate(bounding_box):
    # Blank out initial portion
    index[dim] = slice(None, start)
    ar[tuple(index)] = 0
    # Blank out trailing portion
    index[dim] = slice(stop + 1, None)
    ar[tuple(index)] = 0
    # Reinstate ":"
    index[dim] = slice(None)
```

Comment: With broadcasted assignment, the corner overlap might be an insignificant time penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I was just thinking of this solution

```py
a = np.random.uniform(1, 10, [7, 8]).astype(int)
print(a)

b = np.zeros([7, 8]).astype(int)
b[1:4, 2:5] = 1

print(a * b)
```

Outputs

```
[[8 3 8 5 8 3 5 7]
 [8 8 2 8 5 4 3 5]
 [5 2 2 2 5 1 4 7]
 [5 8 9 3 5 6 4 1]
 [3 6 1 1 4 6 4 8]
 [9 5 2 7 8 2 1 1]
 [1 4 5 4 2 6 2 4]]

[[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 8 5 0 0 0]
 [0 0 2 2 5 0 0 0]
 [0 0 9 3 5 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Not totally satisfied though because it works only if we want 0 out of the bounding box. If we want any other value, then it doesn't work as is.

Comment: Why not? You can use `np.ones` instead and multiply your array by any scalar.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it was already answered, but I will still give a try:

```
import numpy as np

bbox = ((2, 7), (1, 3))

arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 7, 2, 3],
       [4, 3, 2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 5, 2, 1],
       [5, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4],
       [1, 5, 6, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4],
       [7, 4, 5, 6, 2, 5, 3, 5, 6, 7]])

zeros = np.zeros(arr.shape)

zeros[bbox[1][0]:bbox[1][1]+1, 
      bbox[0][0]:bbox[0][1]+1] = arr[bbox[1][0]:bbox[1][1]+1, 
                                     bbox[0][0]:bbox[0][1]+1]

print(zeros)
```

Out:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 4. 5. 5. 6. 5. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 2. 4. 6. 2. 4. 2. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 6. 1. 4. 2. 2. 4. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```